# Navigation Like Bar on Multiple Websites

Tags: javascript, html

I'm currently developing an online learning tool in which users can post links to websites and other users can come along and like or dislike them (adding 1 or deducting 1 to its rating)

At present I'm currently using javascript to create a bookmarklet that once clicked pops up a bar in which users can like or dislike the URL. As expected there are many problems with using this technique; most notable the hassle of having to add the specific javascript into a bookmark.

What I need is a better solution to displaying the like/dislike bar. I was thinking browser extension but that would involve having to code multiple extensions for each different browser. I also considered loading the link within an iframe embedded in the page but iframes are depreciated so I didn't really want to use them.

Wnat I'm wondering is if anyone has any better ideas as to how to display the like bar on the given URLs without users having to go through complicated or annoying installation processes.

Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As you pointed out, there are three possible solutions:

### 1. Websites embed your code voluntarily

This happens with very populare social bookmarking tools only.

Your small service (no pun intented) won't get the market share that people will run after you, so you can forget it.

### 2. A browser extension

The major players do that: Alexa, Google, Yahoo all provide their own browser extension.

The big advantage is that it gives the best user experience.

It has several downsides:

- You need to provide one extension for each browser on each operating system
- The user needs to install it, sometimes requiring admin rights. Not all users have that

You probably don't have the man power to develop them

### 3. A bookmarklet

- Works cross browsers
- Written in a language you already know (Javascript)
- Easy to "install"

There just are no other options for you than to use the bookmarklet.

You should use a script that takes your javascript and packs it into a bookmark. Doing that by hand every time you change something is too chumbersome and you lose joy.